# Pagination is not working in php

Tags: php, html, ajax, pagination

Hi Friends I am Going To paginate my book_search.php which displays the results of the book searched by either title name or author name or publisher name. But the for si=ome search The results are so long , So I need to paginate this result with next and previous buttons. I have Code, but Can u let me know what I need to Change in code for the working of next and previous buttons please.

Thank you In Advance.

Code is below.
`book_search.php`

```
<?php
include('assets/page_header.php');
?>
<div class="container">
   <h1>SEARCHING THE BOOK</h1>

   <form  id="search"  name="search" action="#" method="post">
     Search : <input type="text" name="author" id="author">
    <input id="submit" name="submit"  type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>

   <div id="display"></div>  
</div>
```

`db/ajax.php`

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$page="";
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
   $page=$_GET['page'];
}
$num_rec_per_page = 5;
?>
<div id="navigation">
<?php

if(isset($_POST['author']))
{

    $author=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author']);
    if($author=="")
    {
        echo "Please Enter Title or Author or Publisher";
    }
    else
    {

        if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
        $start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page; 

        $query1="select * from books  where  title LIKE '%$author%' OR author LIKE '%$author%' OR publisher LIKE '%$author%'  LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page  ";
        $rs_result=mysql_query("select * from books  where  title LIKE '%$author%' OR author LIKE '%$author%' OR publisher LIKE '%$author%'"); 


        $total_records = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
        $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 
        //$phpself=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        if($page>1)
        {
        $pagenumber=$page-1;
        $prev="<a href=\"book_search.php?page=$pagenumber\">[Back]</a>";
        $first="<a href=\"book_search.php?page=1\">[FirstPage]</a>";
        }
        else
        {
        $prev='';
        $first='';
        }
        if($page<$total_pages)
        {
        $pagenumber=$page+1;
        $next="<a href=\"book_search.php.?page=$pagenumber\">[Next]</a>";
        $last="<a href=\"book_search.php.?page=$total_pages\">[LastPage]</a>";
        }
        else
        {

        $next="";
        $last="";
        /*$next='[next]';
        $last='[LastPage]';*/
        }


        echo $first.$prev."Showing page<bold>$page</bold>of<bold>$total_pages</bold>pages".$next.$last;

        $result1=mysql_query($query1);
        //print_r($result1);
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result1);
        //echo $count;
        $display= "<table align='center'>";
        $display.= "<tr><td>title</td>   <td>author</td>   <td>publisher</td>   <td>numcopies</td>    <td>status</td>    <td>number_of_copies_available</td> <td>Action</td> </tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
            $count=mysql_num_rows($result1);
            //print_r($row['bookid']);
            $r12=$row['bookid'];
            $query2=mysql_query("select bookid from bookrentalinfo where bookid=$r12");
            $num_copies_borrowed=mysql_num_rows($query2);   
            $num_copies_count=$row['numcopies'];
            $number_of_copies_available=$num_copies_count-$num_copies_borrowed;
            $display.= "<tr>";
            //echo "<td>".$row['bookid']."</td>";
        $display.="<td>".$row['title']."</td>";
            $display.= "<td>".$row['author']."</td>";
            $display.= "<td>".$row['publisher']."</td>";
            $display.= "<td>".$row['numcopies']."</td>";        
            $display.= "<td>".$row['status']."</td>";   
            $display.= "<td>".$number_of_copies_available."</td>";
            if($number_of_copies_available>0)
            {
                $display.= "<td><a href='borrow_search.php?book_id=".$row['bookid']."'>Rent</a></td>";      
            }
            else {
                $display.= "rent link is not activated";
                $display.="<td></td>";      
            }

            $display.= "</tr>";
        }
        $display.="</table>";
        echo $display;
    }

}
?>

    </div>

    </html>
    script.js
$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#renewaldate" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});
    $("#submit").click(function(e){
    //console.log("div value"+$('#display').html());
    var author = $("#author").val();

    /*var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var contact = $("#contact").val();*/
    // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
    //var dataString = 'name1='+ name + '&email1='+ email + '&password1='+ password + '&contact1='+ contact;
    var dataString='author='+author;
    //var dataString = $(this).serializeArray();

        if(author=='')
        {
        alert("Please Enter Author or Title or Publisher Fields");
        }
        else
        {
            // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "db/ajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
            //alert("submitted"+result);
            $('#display').html(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
            }
            });
        }
        e.preventDefault(); 
        });
});
```

Comment: Your form has no action url. Can you let us know how you are passing the form data?

Comment: here the page just redirects to book_search.php with correct page number(get) but it dosen't display any result, i mean it will be blank when i click next or previous button

Comment: Are you getting your $_GET['page'] value properly at the top of the ajax.php?

Comment: Also your url: "db/ajax.php", is not carrying the page value.

Comment: yes bro.........

Comment: I am getting http://localhost/E-LIBRARY2/db/ajax.php?page=2

Comment: here i changed href to db/ajax.php because php code is in db/ajax.php

Comment: Do you get $total_records = mysql_num_rows($rs_result); properly?

Comment: yes I get  correctly there are 16 records i get 16 itself

Comment: Can you change $result1=mysql_query($query1); to $result1=mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: also..you need stop using the mysql_ commands. They are depecrated since PHP7 and pose security risks. Look in to mysqli

Comment: I added die but i am getting nothing in the output

Comment: Can you echo $query1 and run the shown php output on mysql and see

Comment: I will get correct output of records on first page and in sql yog too

Comment: select * from books where title LIKE '%s%' OR author LIKE '%s%' OR publisher LIKE '%s%' LIMIT 0, 5 16Showing page1of4pages[Next][LastPage]
title  author  publisher  numcopies  status  number_of_copies_available  Action
cricket  shaun  marsh  5 AVAILABLE 3 Rent
ss  aa  ss  4 AVAILABLE 3 Rent
ss  aa  ss  3 AVAILABLE 3 Rent
vradhit nayak aa ss 5 AVAILABLE 5 Rent
vradhit nayak ss ddd 3 AVAILABLE 3 Rent

Comment: Please Can Anyone Tell where i went wrong

Comment: Hi, can you please update post with proper file names and code inside them accordingly